# Console.Writeline() Not appearing after a previous Console.Writeline()

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently using Visual Studio in C# Console, my main issue is the line not appearing which is as follows. I have not moved on to the if statement because when I run it it console it will run the first Console.WriteLine I will enter the first input and then console will close at the next key press without running the second Console.WriteLine. That is my problem.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter F or C to define your temperature. Enter F or C here: ");
```

I have tested the first input but it refuses to read that line in console and appears to stop after the second Console.WriteLine. Also if any one has any tips on making a Temperature converting where either F or C can be input that would be just as appreciated as how to fix my issue.

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numberOne;
            int unConvertedTemp;
            bool fahrenheit;
            bool celsius;
            Console.Write("Hello welcome to the temperature converter. Please provide the numerical value of your temperature. Enter your response here:" );
            numberOne = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter F or C to define your temperature. Enter F or C here: ");
            unConvertedTemp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int fToC = ((F - 32) / 9) * 5;
            int cTOF = ((C + 32 / 5) * 9);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to run your code and got values in both numberOne and unCon vertedTemp.  Although it looks like unConvertedTemp is trying to convert to an integer, but you're telling people to pass in either an F or C. This will cause an exception which will end your program. Is this what you're experiencing?

Comment: kindly put your code in correct codeblock.

Comment: No I have yet to include the if value. I currently cannot get my Console to progress past the first input. It will not even show the second WriteLine at all.

Comment: You should do a google search on TryParse. Also your conversions using ints are going to give either errors or improper output. As Joe points out you need an extra readline() at the end to SEE what was output earlier, otherwise the screen closes before you can see it.

Comment: the second writeline won't show up until you enter a value. ReadLine will block until you enter a value and press Enter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe what you're saying is actually true. You say it closes at the next key press but it will only exit at the next "enter" button press.

Your function (and program) are simply exiting before you can see any output. Just put a ReadLine after your final WriteLine so the console waits for you to type "enter" before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your problem is but this should help. You need to use if statements to check what the user input is.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int tempurature;
        string celciusOrFahrenheit;

        Console.Write("Hello welcome to the temperature converter. Please provide the numerical value of your temperature. Enter your response here:");
        tempurature = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter F or C to define your temperature. Enter F or C here: ");
        celciusOrFahrenheit = Console.ReadLine();

        if (celciusOrFahrenheit.ToUpper() == "C")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Temp converted to farenhite: " + ConvertToFahrenheit(tempurature));
        }

        if (celciusOrFahrenheit.ToUpper() == "F")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Temp converted to celcius: " + ConvertToCelcius(tempurature));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int ConvertToFahrenheit(int temp)
    {
        int cToF = ((temp + 32 / 5) * 9);
        return cToF;
    }

    public static int ConvertToCelcius(int temp)
    {
        int fToC = ((temp - 32) / 9) * 5;
        return fToC;
    }
}
```